# Image in pdf is not displa displayed(iTextSharp)

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext

I'm adding image, but it's not displayed correctly and I can't understand why.

I tried to add pictures two ways. ([article about add pictures](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/87/itextsharp-working-with-images))

first way:

```
 iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(xmlNode.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["path"].Value);
```

second way:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(xmlNode.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["path"].Value, FileMode.Open))
{
    iTextSharp.text.Image png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs), ImageFormat.Png);
    
    doc.Add(png);
}
```

and all the time in my PDF is this:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that's all your code? What I see is text and there's no way that adding an image will produce that text.

Comment: @Paulo Soares, I read [it](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/87/itextsharp-working-with-images) and created it in my code. `xmlNode.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["path"].Value` is path to image.

Comment: What is the value of `xmlNode.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["path"].Value`?

Comment: @Amedee Van Gasse, it's path to html page or image, for example, Screenshots/7f1c846e-85af-49d5-b6a0-e432730090d7.jpg and I'm getting right path.

Comment: Ok. It never hurts to double check.

Comment: Oh. Thank you @Paulo Soares and @Amedee Van Gasse. It was my fail. I just didn't see not correct inspection In `if`. Thank You.